# How to find duplicates values in rows?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How to find duplicates values in rows using conditional formatting?

before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the first duplicate instance highlighted? Or why is row 4 highlighted instead of row  6?

Comment: No preference. just find a duplicate in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional column where you use join columns B, C and D

```
=B2&C2&D2
```

[[image]

and in conditional formatting on columns B, C and D use formula

```
=COUNTIF($E:$E;$E2)>1
```

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the column you want to test, and then click the following in the home ribbon:

conditional formatting > highlight cells rules > duplicate values

Repeat this for each column you want to test.

Or if you only want to highlight rows where all values are the same, make a new column that concatenates all the value columns, and test that.